# splitting the large log file in to smaller files as per date

Tags: logging, split

I have a log file size of 2GB of 20days.
I want to split that log files as per date..

I have tried using the below script but its creating files with empty size..

```
#!bin/bash

for year in 2016; do
   for month in jan feb mar apr may jun jul aug sep oct nov dec; do
      for day in 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 31 ; do
cat /export/home//Logs/welogic.log | grep -i $day/$month/$year > $day-$month-$year.log
            done
        done
     done
```

Can anyone help on this..

Comment: which weblogic version are you on? and for which log file do you want to do this? weblogic has built-in rotation for log files.

Answer (score 0):

Under "Servers", click the server whose log files you want to rotate, Then click "Logging"->"General". Here there is a section called "Rotation". Choose the rotation type: By Time. set "Begin rotation time" and "Rotation interval" and you're ready to go. Look for below image for guidance.

Edit: You can also rotate the log file by size. just select "By Size" instead of "By Time".

[image: Rotation]

Comment: Hi Thanks for you answer.

But I want to split the large log files into smaller files..

Comment: then your question has nothing to do with weblogic, right? you just want to split a file by size